# Problem with Raspberry pi camera

Tags: raspicam

So I use the octoprint with my m3d and I have used a USB camera and decided to buy a Raspberry Pi camera module. I get the camera to be detected and supported but I can't access it.

I get:

```
pi@octopi:~ $ raspistill -cs
mmal: mmal_vc_component_enable: failed to enable component: ENOSPC
mmal: camera component couldn't be enabled
mmal: main: Failed to create camera component
mmal: Failed to run camera app. Please check for firmware updates
```

Comment: For future reference it is a great idea to indent each line of your code by 4 spaces.

Answer (score 1):

I had something similar, I think I must have nudged a ribbon. For me re-seating both ends and restarting the pi did the trick. The re-start was essential.

Answer (score 0):

Use `raspi-config` to enable the camera.

If it still doesn't work, you either have a faulty cable or a faulty module (I've had both).

Answer (score 0):

The raspberry pi works with my usb camera fine and the camera led lights. Also the raspi-config camera is enabled.